# Is there some scriptable email client with rich ui?

Tags: email, gui, application

Currently I'm looking for an email client that allows to script dynamic filtering in any language. I know that `mutt` could be scripted, but I work a lot with html5 emails, and I don't like how `mutt` process them. I've already tried `sylpheed`, `thunderbird` - they just can't do what I need.

Do you have any suggestions?

UPD

By "work with html5" I mean to have possibility to display html5 using gui

Comment: what kind of filtering (or other scripting) do you need to do?   thunderbird's got pretty good filtering capabilities built in (i mostly use mutt but TB is OK for the rare occasions when i must use a GUI mail client).

Comment: @cas some powerful. For instance, I'd like to automatically create label for messages that match regex with extracting the label from it :-) As I remember, Thunderbird has not such scriptability power (without extensions, of course). But I will try it out, thanks

Comment: Coming at this late, but for the benefit of future people arriving here via Google as I did: spare yourself endless problems, don't even bother with Thunderbird. I spend almost as much time troubleshooting as I do checking my email. It's been under development for 20 years and it doesn't have basic features, like a usable working search that actually returns the emails you're searching for, yet.